# "Mendeley for electronic literature"

Tags: document-management

Let's say I have a schematic made using components from several manufacturers, I'll need a tool to manage all the documentation corresponding to each component - and being from different manufacturers, they might have different own formats and structures, which may not necessarily comply with technical writing etiquette. Besides, they're all provided in PDF files - portable, as it's meant to be, but not necessarily manageable with convenience.

However, Mendeley does a fair job of organizing scientific literature having similar properties.

Which software tools are designed to be used for managing technical literature such as component datasheets, application notes, white papers, design guides, and errata?

---

Edit:

An app on Linux/Windows, not necessarily accessing the internet for any particular reason, would be appropriate. It should, however, be able to identify or capture metadata from literature files in order to "sync" with the bill-of-materials, for example.

Comment: "I'll need a tool to manage all the documentation corresponding to each component"- why?

Comment: What would such a tool do that isn't just pointing to the location of the pdf of a datasheet? I think you need to give more details on what you seek.

Comment: And don't forget to mention what OS it shall run on, what specific features you need and what your price limit is, please. For a guide, see [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: Well, documentation - at least for a team's internal usage - for what is being created refers to all the documentation for the components, and that translates to managing downloaded documents (@BruceAbbott) as well as accessing metadata from those documents (@JorenVaes).